# wraping powershell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

i'm trying to wrap an already made powershell script with C# GUI client.

the script acts according to inputs from the user, and it has also outputs according to them.

i would like to get the powershell outputs, display them to my C# client and 
and then to enter the input according to his choice.

this is my script, and the code below is what i came up to but it doesn't work.
(i can only get the output at the end, and only if i don't have Read-Host in my powershell script). hope that it helps some how.

```
Write-Host
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
Write-Host "Good-bye World! `n"

$option = Read-Host "Please enter your number"

switch ($option){
  "1"
  {
    Write-Host "jack"
  }
  "2"
  {
    Write-Host "john"
  }
  "3"
  {
    Write-Host "joe"
  }
}

public void WrapPowerShell()
{
        string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"& '{0}'", directory + @"\hello.ps1");
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();



        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // Assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("StringToBeVerifiedInAUnitTest"));

        string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

Big Thanks in advance For your answers!!

Comment: I have not tried your code, but just try giving full explicit path to the Powershell.exe i.e. `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` (on a 64-bit system)

Answer (score 0):

This is a helper class that I wrote to help me create an ASP.NET web app that allowed people to run powershell scripts.

PSHelper.cs

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Text;

namespace admin_scripts {
  public class PSHelper {
    // See the _ps_user_lookup method for demonstration of using this method
    public static Runspace new_runspace() {
      InitialSessionState init_state = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
      init_state.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
      init_state.ImportPSModule(new[] { "ActiveDirectory", "C:\\ps_modules\\disable_user.psm1" });  
                                     // Custom  PS module containing functions related
                                     // to disabling AD accounts at work.
                                     // You would use your own module here, obviously.
      return RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(init_state);
    }

    // This method is for dead-simple scripts that you only want text output from
    // Not as flexible as the previous method, but it's good for the really simple cases
    public static string run_simple_script( string body ) {
      Runspace runspace = new_runspace();
      runspace.Open();

      Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
      pipeline.Commands.AddScript(body);
      pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

      Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
      runspace.Close();

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach( PSObject line in output ) {
        sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

I would invoke a script from an ASP.NET handler like so:

```cs
private PSObject _ps_user_lookup( string id_param ) {
  Runspace runspace = PSHelper.new_runspace();
  runspace.Open();
  using( Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline() ) {
    Command cmd = new Command("Get-ADUser");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Identity", id_param));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Properties", "*"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Server", "REDACTED"));
    pipe.Commands.Add(cmd);
    return pipe.Invoke().FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

The real beauty of this arrangement is that the web application would run the script using the credentials of the web user's domain account.  I hope you find it useful.

Comment: when i try to run the simple script i get the error CmdletInvocationExecption was handled - "Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it."

Comment: do you know what can cause it?

Comment: Not unless I know what cmdlet you're trying to run.  I set this up on a machine that has .NET 4.5, [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887), and maybe PowerShell 3.0.  It is possible that some of this requires any or all of those things.  Don't forget to upvote and accept if it works out for you :D